# Discord like page deep link go_router

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I am building an app, where it has a chat page with discord like transition (left, main and right).

I have stacked the widgets like this

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Left(),
          Main(),
          Right(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using riverpod to maintain the state of the Layouts

I want to land on the main page If a deep link contains a conversation ID

example.com/conversations/:conversationId

The one way is to Pass the layout(left, main, right) in the constructor of MyWidget(), which will trigger a entire build which is pretty expensive.

Since I have initialized some data in splash screen via API

```
class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({super.key});

  @override
  State<Splash> createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Some App initialization logic
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MyHome();
  }
}
```

So, I want some thing like context.go('/conversation/:conversationId'); from any screen which will go to the main layout without rebuilding the entire page.

Please suggest some approach.

I want to approach to handle left, main and right page routes when a link is triggered.

The one idea is by handling it in re-direct block, but I have no idea about avoiding the page pushes, since go_router will push to the particular widget specified in builder or pageBuilder parameters found in GoRoute() widget

Comment: You can use StatefulShellRoute or ShellRoute https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html